# Are there winglet modification regulations?

Tags: regulations, winglets

If an already existing fleet (737-800 and 900 without winglets) is thinking of a winglet modification, is that possible without regulations? Or what are the regulations?

Comment: Aircraft modifications in general are subject to airworthiness update. [CAA (UK)](https://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=1458) // [FAA (US)](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/continued_operation/ad/mcai/).

Comment: Are you referring to the regulatory approval process that declares the plane (type) is airworthy with the addition of the winglet, or the physical installation on an existing plane of a previously approved winglet?

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., changing anything on the wing is considered to be a "Major Repair/Alteration" according to the FAA (**FAR Part 43 - Appendix A**)

To make those changes, this form - http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/Form_337.pdf needs to be completed.

As you can see, it requires a certified mechanic to handle the work after which a person with **Inspection Authorization** would approve the aircraft for return to service.

A little extra reading - [Who can perform different maintenance checks?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/who-can-perform-different-maintenance-checks).

Comment: It's more than checking the change has been done properly. You need to renew the type certificate if a winglet is added, which includes structural tests and flight testing before a mechanic can attach the winglet to the next plane of the same type. Legally, that is.